# Error implies uncertainty or uncertainty implies error?

Tags: error, measurement-error, uncertainty

Just a question in terms of context: 
Error implies uncertainty or uncertainty implies error ?

Say for example, when you are not sure about  your measurement ( i.e. have uncertainty) then you probably have an error. If you have have error in your measurement then you are uncertain about the true value.

So can the two terms be used  interchangeably? Can someone please clarify this for me  ?

Comment: No. Uncertainty is a measure of trust in an answer, an error is a false answer (in context of - lets say classification). If you add a concrete example, then things might be easier to clarify.

Comment: Uncertainty is usually what people experience, as individuals or collectively. That doesn't stop them trying to be as objective as possible about it. Error can mean any kind of variation, including measurement error and sampling error. As Harold Jeffreys  pointed out, the primary sense is erratic rather than erroneous.